# The error occurs if I type 'import tensorflow as tf'

Tags: tensorflow

File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\liuyuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\tensorflow.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Comment: please add the full error log  here

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\liuyuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\tensorflow.py", line 1
    Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: could you also add your code here, looks it's a SyntaxError

Comment: import tensorflow as tf

Comment: is your python script file named tensorflow.py ?

Comment: No, it's not a script. I just code on the Windows cmd

Comment: Hi! What @YuwenYan meant that don't use "tensorflow" for creating python programs else it will create conflicts with tensorflow library. Could you please try again after renaming the tensorflow.py to tensor_flow.py